# difference between histcounts and imhist matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

`histcounts` and `imhist` are not returning the same values for counts and bin locations.

```
x = [0.5000, 0.6429, 0.7143, 0.6429, 0.7857, 0.2857, 0.8571, 0.6429,0, 0.7857, 0.9286, 1.0000, 0.1429, 0.8571, 0.2857, 0.8571, 0.5714, 0.0714];

[c1, l1] = histcounts(x, 6)

c1 =
     3     2     1     4     3     5

l1 =
         0    0.1700    0.3400    0.5100    0.6800    0.8500    1.0200


[c2, l2] = imhist(x, 6)

c2 =
     2     3     0     5     6     2

l2 = 
         0    0.2000    0.4000    0.6000    0.8000    1.0000
```

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB

```
close all;clear all;clc

nbins=[6 16 26 46]

x = [0.5000, 0.6429, 0.7143, 0.6429, 0.7857, 0.2857, 0.8571, ...
    0.6429,0, 0.7857, 0.9286, 1.0000, 0.1429, 0.8571, 0.2857, 0.8571, 0.5714, 0.0714];
```

one can take it from one side

```
for k=1:1:numel(nbins)
    figure(k);
    ax=gca;hold on;grid on
    [C1, L1] = histcounts(x,nbins(k));
    stem(L1(1:end-1),C1);hold on
    [C2, L2] = imhist(x,nbins(k));
    stem(ax,L2,C2)

end
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

or from the other, stem graphs not shown, quite similar to the above ones.

```
for k=1:1:numel(nbins)
    figure(k);
    ax=gca;hold on;grid on
    [C1, L1] = histcounts(x,nbins(k));
    stem(L1(2:end),C1);hold on
    [C2, L2] = imhist(x,nbins(k));
    stem(ax,L2,C2)

end
```

The point : `imhist` is a command for images and it **applies an offset** to all histogram bin locations **depending upon the type of image fed in**.

`imhist` doesn't have a cut-off for tiny images, so the sequence `x` is assumed as image, which it is not.

Read `imhist` [details here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html).

In particular this table shows such offset

[image]

Comment: so for vectors I should always use `histcounts` instead of `imhist`, correct?

Comment: As I am sure you have noticed imshift basically applies a slight offset to all bins, to the left, but histogram doesn't do that unless you pull bin settings and change it.        The point is: when many many bins, not always, but as often done in image processing, it may not matter because the bins are really narrow.   
 But for short samples like the example in your question, histogram is recommended. However, besides such offset, if error tolerable, there's no reason not to use imhist outside image processing, to whatever purpose.

Comment: commands 'hist' and 'histc' are being deprecated by Mathworks. Command histogram is recommended instead. Details here : https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html